# Prevent update notifications for specific packages in Nuget Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm using ServiceStack but I could not buy paid version of it, so I dont want to see newer version of it in my package update list.

I'm using TwitterBootstrap but our theme is compatible with 2.x version of TwitterBootstrap so I dont want to see 3.x version of it Bootstrap in my package update list.

So how can i prevent update notifications for specific packages in Nuget Package Manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [allowedVersions constraint](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning) in your packages.config file for all the packages you want to fix to a particular version.

```
<package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.60" targetFramework="net45" allowedVersions="[3.9.6]"/>
```

With the above in place the Manage Packages dialog will not show any updates for ServiceStack. You will need to add the allowedVersions attribute to all the service stack NuGet packages.

The Package Manager Console will show updates if you use

```
Get-Package -Updates
```

However it will not install anything due to the constraints:

```
Update-Package
Applying constraint 'ServiceStack (= 3.9.6)' defined in packages.config.
No updates available for 'ServiceStack' in project 'MyApp'.
```

Comment: For reference, a more recent [link to the allowedVersions constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/packages-config).

Comment: Unfortunately for me in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019, adding `allowedVersions=""` does not prevent the Manage Packages GUI from listing it in the Updates area - but it does block the update from installing at least (The Package Management GUI is now over 7 years old and still terrible, grrrr)